# JAVA Dentro del metodo asignar valor

Tags: java

No se como dar valor en el metodo a Obra de si esta asignada se debe lanzar una excepción. Está declarada obra como string.
Copio el enunciado, no logro el poder tener el objeto string Obra como único.

Para poder asignar una obra y posteriormente terminarla habrá que implementar los **métodos asignarObra y terminarObra**. El primero recibirá como parámetro el nombre de la obra y el segundo no recibirá ningún parámetro.

- Si el parámetro del método asignarObra es incorrecto, deberá lanzarse una excepción y se detendrá el proceso de instanciación del objeto. En este caso, las posibles excepciones que podrían lanzarse son:
- Si el método recibe un null en obra, la excepción será de tipo NullPointerException y el mensaje de error de la excepción debería ser del tipo "X".
  si el método recibe una cadena vacía en obra, la excepción será de tipo IllegalArgumenException y el mensaje de error de la excepción debería ser del tipo "X".
- Si se intenta asignar una obra pero ya había una obra asignada, se debería lanzar una excepción de tipo IllegalStateException con el mensaje "El teatro ya tiene una obra asignada".
- Del mismo modo, si se intenta terminar una obra sin que haya ninguna asignada, se lanzaría el mismo tipo de excepción IllegalStateException, aunque en este caso con el mensaje "El teatro no tiene una obra asignada que se pueda finalizar".

**La parte principal de mi código.**

```
// Atributos de objeto constantes (representan características inmutables)
private int codigoTeatro;                         // Codigo del teatro
private final String NombreTeatro;                         // Nombre del teatro    
private final int Aforo;                                // Aforo del teatro


// Atributos de objeto variable (representan el estado del vehiculo en un instante dado)
   
private String Obra;                                       // Obra que se está representando
private int EntradasVendidas;                           // Numero de entradas vendidas
```

**Y el código que llevo es el siguiente:**

```
public void asignarObra (String Obra) throws NullPointerException,IllegalStateException ,IllegalArgumentException {
    
    if (this.Obra == null){
        throw new NullPointerException ("El nombre de la obra no puede ser nulo");}
        
    if (this.Obra == ""){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("El nombre de la obra no puede ser cadena vacía");
    }    
    
    if (this.Obra != ""  ){
        throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro ya tiene una obra asignada");}

}
    
   
public void terminarObra() throws IllegalArgumentException {
    
if (this.Obra != null){
    throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro no tiene una obra asignada que se pueda finalizar");}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola yo haría las siguiente modificaciones:

Para el método `asignarObra`:

- Eliminar el throws del metodo `asignarObra`, ya que todas las exceptiones son `unchecked` y no es necesario declararlas.
- Cuando utilizas `this.Obra` te refieres al atributo de tu clase, y cuando te refieres solo a `Obra`, estas indicando el parametro del método. Entonces en las validaciones debes tomar en cuenta eso.

Para el metodo `terminarObra`:

- De igual manera podrias eliminar el throws de la declaracion del método ya que es de tipo `unchecked`.
- Verificar que si la obra es nula, lanzar la excepción.

```
public void asignarObra(String Obra) {
    //Verificar si el parametro obra es nulo
    if (Obra == null){
        throw new NullPointerException ("El nombre de la obra no puede ser nulo");}
     // verificar si el parametro obra esta vacio
    if (Obra.equals("")){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("El nombre de la obra no puede ser cadena vacía");
    }    
    // verificar si no existe una obra ya asignada
    if (this.Obra != null  ){
        throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro ya tiene una obra asignada");}

   // asignar al atributo el valor del parametro.
   this.Obra = Obra;

}
    
   
public void terminarObra() {
    
if (this.Obra == null){
    throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro no tiene una obra asignada que se pueda finalizar");}

}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Solucionado